# What's the correct way to pass environment variables to a keyed function and how could it be used with the KeyedOneInputStreamOperatorTestHarness

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I need to pass some configuration to a custom *KeyedProcessFunction* and I would like to test it with *KeyedOneInputStreamOperatorTestHarness*. What's the proper way to handle this?

I've looked to the docs but when searching for configurations the results point to the list of existing configs in flink.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the configuration to the KeyedProcessFunction's constructor. Something like this:

```java
DataStream<Event> stream = events
    .keyBy(event -> event.key)
    .process(new Example(config));
```

```java
public static class Example extends KeyedProcessFunction<K, I, O> {

    private final CONFIG config;

    public Example(CONFIG config) {
        this.config = config;
    }

    ...
}
```

Then in your test you can supply whatever config you want:

```java
private final KeyedProcessFunction<K, I, O> functionToTest = new Example(config);

KeyedProcessOperator<K, I, O> operator = new KeyedProcessOperator<>(function);

KeyedOneInputStreamOperatorTestHarness<K, I, O> testHarness =
    new KeyedOneInputStreamOperatorTestHarness<>(operator, ...);
```

Comment: Thank you David, sometimes the solution is so simple that we fail to see it.